# Slider responsivo em css

Tags: css, slider

Como deixar meu `slider` responsivo. Já digitei todos os códigos, e ele está em `css` puro ( fiz ele a partir de galerias que baixei na internet, que servem para alterar cor, icones, etc.) ai gostaria de saber o codigo que devo colocar e onde devo implatá-lo, para deixar meu `slider` responsivo.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<title>Slider UNIP</title>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/vendor/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/gallery.prefixed.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../dist/gallery.theme.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="gallery items-3">
        <div id="item-1" class="control-operator"></div>
        <div id="item-2" class="control-operator"></div>
        <div id="item-3" class="control-operator"></div>

        <figure class="item">
            <img src="C:\Users\jose\Desktop\css\gallery-css-master\examples\standard\agua1.jpg" />
        </figure>

        <figure class="item">
            <img src="C:\Users\jose\Desktop\css\gallery-css-master\examples\standard\agua3.jpg" />
        </figure>

        <figure class="item">
            <img src="C:\Users\jose\Desktop\css\gallery-css-master\examples\standard\agua2.png" />
        </figure>

        <div class="controls">
            <a href="#item-1" class="control-button">•</a>
            <a href="#item-2" class="control-button">•</a>
            <a href="#item-3" class="control-button">•</a>

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você pode utilizar o media screen através do css, ou pode utilizar algum pronto, já pensou nisso? Dou exemplo do Flexslider que contém a opção de touch habilitada e é responsivo, sem contar que é bem fácil de implementar/personalizar, segue link: http://flexslider.woothemes.com/

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar uma tag de `<style>` dentro do arquivo para testar rapidamente e depois passar para o arquivo css se quiser. Dentro dessa tag você pode usar o Media Query onde vc especifica o tamanho da tela e como o seu slider deve ficar. Segue um exemplo:

```
<style>
@media (max-width: 800px){
    .gallery {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .controls {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
</style>
```

Isso faz o browser entender que quando a tela tiver menos ou igual 800px de largura o seu slider deve ter tamanho (width) igual a 100%. A partir dai voce pode especificar tamanho da tela e valores para o slider.